# RestKit objectStore doesn't save after reset

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

In RestKit's `didLoadObjects` I modify some attributes of  the returned objects then use `[[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore] save:&error];` to save them to the context. That's working with no problems.

Later on, when a user logs out, I use the code below to reset the CoreData store:

```
RKManagedObjectStore *objectStore = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectStore];
[objectStore deletePersistentStore];
[objectStore save:nil];
```

Afterward when I request the same data again and try to do the same thing in `didLoadObjects` they never get saved. I've made sure the object store is not nil and that the save method doesn't return an error.